# If I buy a new fan online will the genius bar install it for me?

Tags: macbook-pro

I need a replacement fan and they only cost about $10 online. If I take it to the genius bar, will they install it for me?

Answer (score 4):

No, they will not. They will only install equipment that you purchase at the Apple Store.